# How to read text file in react

Tags: reactjs, text-files, readfile

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hULjz.jpg)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZvWD.jpg)

I want to read from a text file within the react project, but when I try to execute and read I get a HTML sample code in the console log.

This is the function:

```
onclick= () =>{
 fetch('data.txt')
  .then(function(response){
    return response.text();
  }).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
};
```

And the button which calls it:

```
<button onClick={this.onclick}>click string</button>
```

Comment: what you mean by 'htm sample code'?
have you tried `./data.txt`?

Comment: The first answer can be accepted, but that is something that will not work unless you will add loader for webpack configurations, which will allow you to import text file. You can check [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) (A loader for webpack that allows importing files as a String.)

Comment: @Drusto i have and same results, This is a bit of the output: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut ico"

Answer (score 67):

Simply try the below code and you may understand

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  showFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = async (e) => { 
      const text = (e.target.result)
      console.log(text)
      alert(text)
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])
  }

  render = () => {

    return (<div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.showFile(e)} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Came here looking for THIS answer, as loading a file from the app itself wasn't the issue that led me here.

Answer (score 46):

If you want to get a .txt file first you have to import it:

```
import raw from '../constants/foo.txt';
```

After that, you could fetch it and transform into text:

```
fetch(raw)
 .then(r => r.text())
 .then(text => {
  console.log('text decoded:', text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem of trying to load a YAML file. `fs` didn't work, so I'm glad that `fetch` did!

Comment: Got "Cannot find module '../foo1/foo2.txt' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: @Benur21 you can add the following code in Declaration File(d.ts) `declare module '*.txt';`

Answer (score 18):

> Try below approach :

```
import text from './data.js'; // The relative path to your File

console.log(text);
```

Create a file called data.js and add below content :

```
const text = "My Text goes here";

export default text;
```

Comment: Please post screenshot of you code and the code structure

Comment: I cannot see above code in screenshot 1, you still using old approach

Comment: i am not following you

Comment: `import { text } from './data.txt';` this line is in your code?

Comment: no it is not but when i paste it remains as an unused import

Comment: Remove all code from your onClick and just use console as i did above and make sure you import the above line

Comment: still the same results

Comment: changing "import { text } from './data.js'"; to "import text from './data.js';" made it work for me

Comment: `Attempted import error: 'text' is not exported from './data.js'.`

Answer (score 0):

As React is JavaScript, so this code should work.

Html

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="onLoad(event)">
```

JavaScript

```
onLoad = function (event){
 var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;
    
    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var content = reader.result;
            // Here the content has been read successfuly
            alert(content);
        }
        
        reader.readAsText(file);    
    } 
}
```

Event this will work, if directly on page load if you want to load the data.

```
import { text } from './data.txt'; // Relative path to your File
console.log(text);
```