# Read internal excel file using React

Tags: reactjs, excel

I have an excel file stored in src folder. I want to use react to read the excel file directly instead of uploading a file using input field and show the object array to the console, does anyone know how to do it? Any reference link about that? I saw a lot about uploading an excel file and output the data, but I don't want to upload the file. I want to import the file directly or fetch data from the file. Let me know if you know how to do in react. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Here's a link to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830414/how-to-read-text-file-in-react). You could parse/read the excel file using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file).

A little suggestion, would be to use .csv or .json files instead of .xlsx files, if you are only dealing in data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  fetch(excelFile).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
       .then((ab) => {
           const wb        = XLSX.read(ab, { type: "array" });
           const sheetname = wb.SheetNames[0]
           const ws        = wb.Sheets[sheetname]
           const json      = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws,{header: 1,defval:''})
           console.log(json)
```

Here excelFile is file location, you may include your excel file location, Then json contain excel data.

Thanks.